# Git pull resolving conflict, remote is one aheady

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have introduced a conflict within my git repository local / remote.  Here is what I did, both my local and remote were synced, but then I edited the readme file from the Bitbucket GUI causing a new commit, without thinking about it, I then edited my local repository adding ton of code, now I can't push to the remote.  Sadly I have had this issue before and worked around it in a very inefficient way.  Is there a simple efficient way to resolve this, ensuring I don't lose my local changes?  The readme changes I made through the GUI I really don't give a darn about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

- rebase your work on top of the upstream branch:
  (It changes your local history, but only for the commit or commits that you didn't pushed yet, so it is ok)

  ```
  git pull --rebase
  git push
  ```
- or simply force the push (loosing the change on the readme, unless you copy said change locally first)

  ```
  git push --force
  ```

Comment: I used the git push --force method, seemed simplest and I didn't need to preserve what was in the remote repo

Answer (score 0):

You only need to

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

Then you can push again